# View Pager inside detail fragment of master detail flow is called but not shown

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, master-detail

I've set up a view pager inside the detail of a master detail flow activity it seems to be working (prints logs) but the view isn't appearing so here is the recipe detail layout that holds the view pager this is the detail fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".recipeDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="recipe detail"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the text view above does show in the layout when i run the app, the view pager should be loading a layout for each item in a list (list definitely has items inside) this layout also has a big text view (just for testing purposes) but this layout doesn't show, here is the entire adapter for my view pager as its not got anything complicated inside

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Step> steps;
private String TAG = "CstmPgAdptr";

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Step> adapterSteps) {
    mContext = context;
    this.steps = adapterSteps;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    Step step = steps.get(position);
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_detail, collection,false);
    TextView descriptionText = layout.findViewById(R.id.recipe_detail);
    descriptionText.setText(step.getDescription());
    Log.d(TAG,"new view called");
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    collection.removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return CustomPagerEnum.values().length;
    return steps.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return steps.get(position).getShortDescription();
}

}
```

when i swipe on the fragment that holds the view pager this log Log.d(TAG,"new view called"); is printed everytime which means it is working but not being shown, also there is no scroll views in any layouts (seen that can be an issue)

**EDIT**

recipe detail layout added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".recipeDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_padding"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_detail_text"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/video_view"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recipe_detail2"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: take your viewpager and textview in another layout like frame, linear or relative

Comment: just changed to a relative layout still nothing logs still printing

Comment: you should be inflating a different view other your recipe_detail view in your view pager.

Comment: ive added the other layout, ive also tried just inflating any old random layout and it isn't displayed either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok that was my fault. I added this

```
collection.addView(layout);
```

and it is working fine